# Web2Py getting/posting values

Tags: python, database, web2py

I'm fairly new to Web2Py and i'm hoping for some help.

I have a reviews DB and a games DB.

At the moment the user can click on a game from a list and they are taken to a page allowing them to leave a review.

I can save the review into the DB but I can't get it to reference the corresponding game.

DB:

```
db.define_table('games',
            Field('title',requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
            Field('description','text',requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()))

db.define_table('reviews',
            Field('title',requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
            Field('review','text',requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()))
```

Default.py:

```
def review():
getTitle = db.games(request.args(0)) or redirect(URL('default', 'index'))
formReview = SQLFORM(db.reviews,fields = ['title','review']).process()
if formReview.accepted: redirect(URL('index'))
return dict(formReview=formReview, getTitle=getTitle)
```

Review.html:

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}
<h2>Review a game</h2>
<h2>{{=getTitle.title}}</h2>
{{=formReview}}
```

I'm guessing I need to create a field in 'reviews' that will get the 'request.args' value. But i'm not sure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first expand your `review` table to hold a `foreign key` to the `games` table like this:

```
db.define_table('reviews',
            Field('title',requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
            Field('review','text',requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
            Field('game_id', 'reference games'))
```

So you have a reference for which game the review is. With this aditional information you should be able to select all reviews for a game and render them in the view.

```
for row in db(db.reviews.game_id == 1).select():
    print row.title   # just an example
```

And of course you also need to save the corresponding `game_id` when creating a new review entry ;)

```
formReview = SQLFORM(db.reviews,fields = ['game_id', 'title','review']).process()
```

Comment: So the final line you posted, do i insert that after 'formReview.accepted:'?

Comment: Thanks, the only thing is I'm hoping it will post the game ID automatically, as these will be unique in the games table.

Comment: @user2966455 Did you solve your problem? If you think the answer was usefull, an upvote/accept would be nice ;)